# How do I generate very large images from an RGB array?

Tags: python, image, png

How can I convert an array containing RGB color values like this into an image using Python?

```
[
  [(0, 255, 0), (40, 24, 10), (0, 10, 250)...],
  [(100, 40, 64), (102, 39, 11), (20, 1, 2)...],
  ...
]
```

Each row is a horizontal line of the image, and each tuple is one RGB pixel. I will be processing very large images (16384x16384 or bigger), so it can't load the whole image in RAM at once. PNG output is preferred, though BMP is also OK.

Comment: You can't load the whole image in memory? Where is it then? Where does it come from?

Comment: You can write it incrementally into a `NetPBM` file of type PPM.

Comment: How are you going to deal with it after it's converted if you can't read it into memory?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It'll be from a file.
I'll write it to my hard drive, and view it using an image viewer that can view very large images.